# Opción de retorno a condición "if" en Python 3 por opción ingresada desde teclado

Tags: python, python-3.x

En una parte de mi código realizo una pregunta en pantalla. La pregunta como respuesta requiere de un "si" o "no", pero cuando escriban mal u otra cosa me gustaría que el código retorne y pregunté nuevamente hasta que el usuario ingrese correctamente la opción.

Lo que estoy haciendo es lo siguiente:

```
print("RESPONDA con si o no")
clave=input()
if clave=="N" or clave=="NO" or clave=="no" or clave=="No" or clave=="n" or clave=="nO":
    print("ok")
```

¿Alguien sabe como arreglar esto? Se me ocurre con un `while` que esté en el bucle mientras responda bien, terminando esto con un `break`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrias solucionarlo asi:

```
while(True):
    print("RESPONDA con sí o no")
    clave=input()
    if clave.upper()=="N" or clave.upper()=="NO": 
        print("ok")
        break
    elif clave.upper()=="S" or clave.upper()=="SI":
        print("otro ok")    
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

No necesitas usar `break`. La condición de tu `while` es la que hará que el bucle se detenga. Solo necesitas tres líneas para esto:

```
>>> clave = ''
>>> while clave.upper() not in ('N', 'NO', 'S', 'SI'):
...     clave = input('¿Quieres continuar? (S/N): ')
... 
¿Quieres continuar? (S/N): dasda
¿Quieres continuar? (S/N): cxxczxc
¿Quieres continuar? (S/N): n
>>>
```

Después del bloque `while` puedes procesar lo que necesitas con el resultado final:

```
if clave.upper() in ('S', 'SI'):
    # Procesar respuesta afirmativa
else:
    # Procesar respuesta negativa
```

Answer (score 2):

Un `while` debería poder hacerlo:

```
notCalculated = true
while(notCalculated):
    print("RESPONDA con si o no") 
    clave=input() 
    if clave=="N" or clave=="NO" or clave=="no" or clave=="No" or clave=="n" or clave=="nO": 
       print("ok")
       notCalculated = false
```

No soy un experto en Python pero otros lenguajes tienen un comando llamado break` si Python lo tiene haz:

```
while(true) :
    print("RESPONDA con si o no") clave=input()
    if clave=="N" or clave=="NO" or clave=="no" or clave=="No" or clave=="n" or clave=="nO": 
        print("ok")
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción es  inlcuir la condición en el `while`, así:

```
clave = ""
while (not(clave=="N" or clave=="no" or clave=="No" or clave=="n" or clave=="nO")):
    print("Responda sí o no")
    clave = input()
print("ok") #afuera del ciclo
```

Como está en la respuesta de @Julio, puedes omitir algunos `or` con `upper()`, así lo haces *case insensitive* o *insensible a mayúsculas*